# create device mapper target

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-mapper

I am trying to implement device mapper target by referring to the already existing ones dm-linear, dm-snapshot, dm-cache etc. In my implementation, I need to perform a read/modify/write operation on a certain sector range. Since the device mapper directly talks to the block layer, I am not sure what data structures/functions to use to read the sectors in the memory, modify the buffer and write it back to another sector range.
At the application level, we have syscalls and below we have vfs_read/vfs_write. Is there anything similar for device mapper layer?
I have been stuck here for very long. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NOTE: My answer is related to kernel version < 3.14, because since 3.14 API is slightly changed.

In kernel you read/write certain sectors with [`struct bio`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/blk_types.h?v=3.13#L35). This struct is used for all block level I/O. Comprehensive documentation can be found [in kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/block/biodoc.txt?v=3.13) and on [lwn](http://lwn.net/Articles/26404/). These are the several most significant members of this structure:

- `bio->bi_sector` - first sector of block I/O request
- `bio->bi_size` - size of I/O request
- `bio->bi_bdev` - device to read/write
- `bio->bi_end_io` - callback that kernel will call on the end of request

What you do in device mapper target is **map incoming `bio`**. When you creating your device mapper target you supply at least 2 callbacks: `ctr`, and `map`. For example, the simplest device-mapper target *dm-zero* declares it's callbacks [as following](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/md/dm-zero.c?v=3.13#L56):

```
static struct target_type zero_target = {
         .name   = "zero",
         .version = {1, 1, 0},
         .module = THIS_MODULE,
         .ctr    = zero_ctr,
         .map    = zero_map,
};
```

`map` is a key callback - it's a heart of every device-mapper target. `map` receive incoming `bio` and it can do anything with it. For example, dm-linear just shift sector of every incoming `bio` by predefined offset. See the code:

```
static sector_t linear_map_sector(struct dm_target *ti, sector_t bi_sector)
{
        struct linear_c *lc = ti->private;

        return lc->start + dm_target_offset(ti, bi_sector);
}

static void linear_map_bio(struct dm_target *ti, struct bio *bio)
{
        struct linear_c *lc = ti->private;

        bio->bi_bdev = lc->dev->bdev;
        if (bio_sectors(bio))
                bio->bi_sector = linear_map_sector(ti, bio->bi_sector);
}

static int linear_map(struct dm_target *ti, struct bio *bio)
{
        linear_map_bio(ti, bio);

        return DM_MAPIO_REMAPPED;
}
```

Because map receives pointer to `bio` it can change value under that pointer and that's it.

That's how you map I/O requests. If you want to create your own requests then you must allocate `bio`, fill it's sector, device, size, end callback and add buffers to read into/write from. Basically, it's just a few steps:

- Call to bio_alloc to allocate bio.
- Set `bio->bi_bdev`, `bio->bi_sector`, `bio->bi_size`, `bio->bi_end_io`
- Add pages via `bio_add_page`.
- Call `submit_bio`.
- Handle results and errors in `bio->bi_end_io` callback

Example can be found in *dm-crypt* target in [`crypt_alloc_buffer`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/md/dm-crypt.c?v=3.13#L983) function.

Comment: Thanks @avd, This is really helpful. Do you think I can do the same rmw operation using [dm-bufio.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/md/dm-bufio.c). I want to read a range of sectors, modify some of those sectors and the write the data into a new range. it is similar to what we do in circular buffers.

Comment: It seems <linux/dm-bufio.h> does not exist while compiling

Comment: dm-bufio is internal device-mapper header. It is not export via include/linux directory. The only way I can see to use it is create your own dm target in kernel tree - under drivers/md/dm-ours-target.c and compile it inside kernel. There you can include it like `#include "dm-bufio.h"`.